# Download any Android apps on SD card

Tags: downloading

How can we download the files directly to SD card rather than phone memory on Android phones?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say: without rooting the device, it's quite unlikely to be possible.

On a rooted device, one could symlink the download folder to a folder located on the SDCard, and thus trick the system to directly download to the card (the way Link2SD works with installing apps on SDCard).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible AFAIK

Look at those two links:

http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-applications/246277-download-install-apps-sd-card.html

http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-precedent/620201-there-way-download-apps-straight-sd-card.html

but you can download it and move to sd card. For that see [this link](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/manufacturers/LG/discussions/How-do-I-downloadmove-apps-to-SD-card_id270)